# LXD Container in ERROR State

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, zfs, lxd

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system where i created 3 LXD containers. They where working fine. The system was reseted without stopping the containers by accident. Now they are in a ERROR state and I cannot start them. When i try to start any of them i get the same error (i get it even if i try to delete them):

> error: Unable to import the ZFS pool: cannot import 'lxd': no such
>   pool available

Is there any way i can recover them?

My system is:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
LXC/LXD version 2.011
ZFS v0.6.5.6-0ubuntu20
```

With `lxc list`  i get the following result:

```
+-----------+-------+------+------+------------+-----------+
|   NAME    | STATE | IPV4 | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-----------+-------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| cups-lxc  | ERROR |      |      | PERSISTENT |           |
+-----------+-------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| mongo-lxc | ERROR |      |      | PERSISTENT |           |
+-----------+-------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| mysql-lxc | ERROR |      |      | PERSISTENT |           |
+-----------+-------+------+------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: *i get it even if i try to delete them* - If they are not important, remove and install LXD again, also look into using the snap package as so many bugs have been fixed, plus many improvements since v2, the issue is unlikely to happen again.

Comment: So you have an issue with ZFS it sounds like not LXC. Do a zpool status and zpool list. We fix whatever happened to ZFS and we fix your containers. I use ZFS with ProxMox.. never had an issue like that yet. But do those commands and report back.

Comment: @Frank  when i do zpool status or zpool list it says **no pools available**

Comment: Bleh, wow, how did that happen I wonder. Alright try this and see what you get.  zpool import.  You should hopefully see a response of a pool name and ID.  If so do a zpool import name.  If that works, do the zpool list status commands I said in my earlier post..

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `zpool list` shows no pool means that you need to run `zpool import <pool name>` first. If you want to be more cautious, you can run it without the pool name to get a list of all zpools that ZFS can find on the disks attached to the system (but you shouldn’t need to do that, since importing will not cause any damage anyway).